My custom type has many different properties with most of them being optional, how I can make it more compact
I'm developing a tool for modding a game and I want to remake custom type as C# class. This type has 1 required property and many other optional ones. I'm getting all of the data for custom class from XML file, so is there any way I can make this constructor better?
    public class Item(
         string identifier,
         string? nameIdentifier = null,
         string? fallbackNameIdentifier = null,
         string? descriptionIdentifier = null,
         string? name = null,
         string? aliases = null,
         string? tags = null,
         Item.Categories? category = null,
         bool? allowAsExtraCargo = null,
         float? interactDistance = null,
         float? interactPriority = null,
         bool? interactThroughWalls = null,
         bool? hideConditionBar = null,
         bool? hideConditionInTooltip = null,
         bool? requireBodyInsideTrigger = null,
         bool? requireCursorInsideTrigger = null,
         bool? requireCampaignInteract = null,
         bool? focusOnSelected = null,
         float? offsetOnSelected = null,
         float? health = null,
         bool? allowSellWhenBroken = null,
         bool? indestructible = null,
         bool? damagedByExplosions = null,
         float? explosionDamageMultiplier = null,
         bool? damagedByProjectiles = null,
         bool? damagedByMeleeWeapons = null,
         bool? damagedByRepairTools = null,
         bool? damagedByMonsters = null,
         bool? fireProof = null,
         bool? waterProof = null,
         float? impactTolerance = null,
         float? onDamagedThreshold = null,
         float? sonarSize = null,
         bool? useInHealthInterface = null,
         bool? disableItemUsageWhenSelected = null,
         string? cargoContainerIdentifier = null,
         bool? useContainedSpriteColor = null,
         bool? useContainedInventoryIconColor = null,
         float? addedRepairSpeedMultiplier = null,
         float? addedPickingSpeedMultiplier = null,
         bool? cannotRepairFail = null,
         string? equipConfirmationText = null,
         bool? allowRotatingInEditor = null,
         bool? showContentsInTooltip = null,
         bool? canFlipX = null,
         bool? canFlipY = null,
         bool? isDangerous = null,
         int? maxStackSize = null,
         bool? allowDroppingOnSwap = null,
         bool? resizeHorizontal = null,
         bool? resizeVertical = null,
         string? description = null,
         string? allowedUpgrades = null,
         bool? hideInMenus = null,
         string? subcategory = null,
         bool? linkable = null,
         string? spriteColor = null,
         float? scale = null)
    {
        public enum Categories
        {
            Decorative,
            Machine,
            Medical,
            Weapon,
            Diving,
            Equipment,
            Fuel,
            Electrical,
            Material,
            Alien,
            Wrecked,
            Misc
        }

        // All of Item attributes
        public required string identifier = identifier;
        public string? nameIdentifier = nameIdentifier;
        public string? fallbackNameIdentifier = fallbackNameIdentifier;
        public string? descriptionIdentifier = descriptionIdentifier;

        public string? name = name;
        public string? aliases = aliases;
        public string? tags = tags;
        public Categories? category = category;

        public bool? allowAsExtraCargo = allowAsExtraCargo;
        public float? interactDistance = interactDistance;
        public float? interactPriority = interactPriority;
        public bool? interactThroughWalls = interactThroughWalls;

        public bool? hideConditionBar = hideConditionBar;
        public bool? hideConditionInTooltip = hideConditionInTooltip;
        public bool? requireBodyInsideTrigger = requireBodyInsideTrigger;
        public bool? requireCursorInsideTrigger = requireCursorInsideTrigger;

        public bool? requireCampaignInteract = requireCampaignInteract;
        public bool? focusOnSelected = focusOnSelected;
        public float? offsetOnSelected = offsetOnSelected;
        public float? health = health;

        public bool? allowSellWhenBroken = allowSellWhenBroken;
        public bool? indestructible = indestructible;
        public bool? damagedByExplosions = damagedByExplosions;
        public float? explosionDamageMultiplier = explosionDamageMultiplier;

        public bool? damagedByProjectiles = damagedByProjectiles;
        public bool? damagedByMeleeWeapons = damagedByMeleeWeapons;
        public bool? damagedByRepairTools = damagedByRepairTools;
        public bool? damagedByMonsters = damagedByMonsters;

        public bool? fireProof = fireProof;
        public bool? waterProof = waterProof;
        public float? impactTolerance = impactTolerance;
        public float? onDamagedThreshold = onDamagedThreshold;

        public float? sonarSize = sonarSize;
        public bool? useInHealthInterface = useInHealthInterface;
        public bool? disableItemUsageWhenSelected = disableItemUsageWhenSelected;
        public string? cargoContainerIdentifier = cargoContainerIdentifier;

        public bool? useContainedSpriteColor = useContainedSpriteColor;
        public bool? useContainedInventoryIconColor = useContainedInventoryIconColor;
        public float? addedRepairSpeedMultiplier = addedRepairSpeedMultiplier;
        public float? addedPickingSpeedMultiplier = addedPickingSpeedMultiplier;

        public bool? cannotRepairFail = cannotRepairFail;
        public string? equipConfirmationText = equipConfirmationText;
        public bool? allowRotatingInEditor = allowRotatingInEditor;
        public bool? showContentsInTooltip = showContentsInTooltip;

        public bool? canFlipX = canFlipX;
        public bool? canFlipY = canFlipY;
        public bool? isDangerous = isDangerous;
        public int? maxStackSize = maxStackSize;

        public bool? allowDroppingOnSwap = allowDroppingOnSwap;
        public bool? resizeHorizontal = resizeHorizontal;
        public bool? resizeVertical = resizeVertical;
        public string? description = description;

        public string? allowedUpgrades = allowedUpgrades;
        public bool? hideInMenus = hideInMenus;
        public string? subcategory = subcategory;
        public bool? linkable = linkable;

        public string? spriteColor = spriteColor;
        public float? scale = scale;

        public List<XmlElement>? children = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets this Item represent
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>XmlElement represent of the Item</returns>
        public XmlElement GetAsXml()
        {
            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new();
            XmlElement newItem = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Item");

            foreach(var attr in this.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                if (attr.GetValue(this, null) != null)
                {
                    newItem.SetAttribute(attr.Name.ToLower(), value: attr.GetValue(this, null).ToString());
                }
            }

            newItem.InnerText = "";

            if (this.children != null)
            {
                foreach (var child in this.children)
                {
                    newItem.AppendChild(child);
                }
            }

            return newItem;
        }
    }
}

I have thought of 2 ways this can potentially be done, passing properties either as a dictionary or a new custom type containing all of available properties, but I'm not sure if they would be any better.

First of all: there is not one property, here. They all sem to be public fields.

If you are free to make changes, I'd suggest to look at those fields individually and a) make them actual properties (probably using a "proper" ctor, or even just the default one). Then b) you could subgroup some that are related into their own types, maybe merge some into Flag-Enums ...

How about this, define a class to hold all your optional properties:
public class ItemData
{
     public string? nameIdentifier { get; set; } = null;
     public string? fallbackNameIdentifier { get; set; } = null;
     public string? descriptionIdentifier { get; set; } = null;
     public string? name { get; set; } = null;
     public string? aliases { get; set; } = null;
     public string? tags { get; set; } = null;
     public ItemData.Categories? category { get; set; } = null;
     public bool? allowAsExtraCargo { get; set; } = null;
     public float? interactDistance { get; set; } = null;
     public float? interactPriority { get; set; } = null;
     public bool? interactThroughWalls { get; set; } = null;
     public bool? hideConditionBar { get; set; } = null;
     public bool? hideConditionInTooltip { get; set; } = null;
     public bool? requireBodyInsideTrigger { get; set; } = null;
     public bool? requireCursorInsideTrigger { get; set; } = null;
     public bool? requireCampaignInteract { get; set; } = null;
     public bool? focusOnSelected { get; set; } = null;
     public float? offsetOnSelected { get; set; } = null;
     public float? health { get; set; } = null;
     public bool? allowSellWhenBroken { get; set; } = null;
     public bool? indestructible { get; set; } = null;
     public bool? damagedByExplosions { get; set; } = null;
     public float? explosionDamageMultiplier { get; set; } = null;
     public bool? damagedByProjectiles { get; set; } = null;
     public bool? damagedByMeleeWeapons { get; set; } = null;
     public bool? damagedByRepairTools { get; set; } = null;
     public bool? damagedByMonsters { get; set; } = null;
     public bool? fireProof { get; set; } = null;
     public bool? waterProof { get; set; } = null;
     public float? impactTolerance { get; set; } = null;
     public float? onDamagedThreshold { get; set; } = null;
     public float? sonarSize { get; set; } = null;
     public bool? useInHealthInterface { get; set; } = null;
     public bool? disableItemUsageWhenSelected { get; set; } = null;
     public string? cargoContainerIdentifier { get; set; } = null;
     public bool? useContainedSpriteColor { get; set; } = null;
     public bool? useContainedInventoryIconColor { get; set; } = null;
     public float? addedRepairSpeedMultiplier { get; set; } = null;
     public float? addedPickingSpeedMultiplier { get; set; } = null;
     public bool? cannotRepairFail { get; set; } = null;
     public string? equipConfirmationText { get; set; } = null;
     public bool? allowRotatingInEditor { get; set; } = null;
     public bool? showContentsInTooltip { get; set; } = null;
     public bool? canFlipX { get; set; } = null;
     public bool? canFlipY { get; set; } = null;
     public bool? isDangerous { get; set; } = null;
     public int? maxStackSize { get; set; } = null;
     public bool? allowDroppingOnSwap { get; set; } = null;
     public bool? resizeHorizontal { get; set; } = null;
     public bool? resizeVertical { get; set; } = null;
     public string? description { get; set; } = null;
     public string? allowedUpgrades { get; set; } = null;
     public bool? hideInMenus { get; set; } = null;
     public string? subcategory { get; set; } = null;
     public bool? linkable { get; set; } = null;
     public string? spriteColor { get; set; } = null;
     public float? scale { get; set; } = null;

    public enum Categories
    {
        Decorative,
        Machine,
        Medical,
        Weapon,
        Diving,
        Equipment,
        Fuel,
        Electrical,
        Material,
        Alien,
        Wrecked,
        Misc
    }
}

And pass the ItemData class to the Item constructor:
 public class Item
 {
     public string Identifier { get; private set; }
     public ItemData OptionalData { get; private set; }
     public List<XmlElement>? Children { get; private set; } = null;
     public Item(string identifier, ItemData optionalData)
     {
         Identifier = identifier;
         OptionalData = optionalData;

         // Get the name
         string? name = OptionalData.name;
     }
 }

You will also have to update your Item.GetAsXml() method to correctly serialize your data:
public XmlElement GetAsXml()
{
    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new();
    XmlElement newItem = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Item");

    // Identifier
    PropertyInfo identInfo = this.GetType().GetProperty(nameof(Identifier));
    newItem.SetAttribute(identInfo.Name.ToLower(), value: identInfo.GetValue(this, null).ToString());

    // Optional data attributes
    foreach (var attr in OptionalData.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        if (attr.GetValue(OptionalData, null) != null)
        {
            newItem.SetAttribute(attr.Name.ToLower(), value: attr.GetValue(OptionalData, null).ToString());
        }
    }

    newItem.InnerText = "";

    if (this.Children != null)
    {
        foreach (var child in this.Children)
        {
            newItem.AppendChild(child);
        }
    }

    return newItem;
}

You can then create items like:
 ItemData itemData = new ItemData();
 itemData.name = "name1";
 itemData.health = 99;
 Item item = new Item("identifier1", itemData);

When you serialize the above item:
 XmlElement xml = item.GetAsXml();
 Debug.WriteLine(xml.OuterXml);

You get this output:
<Item identifier="identifier1" name="name1" health="99"></Item>


This is actually a pretty nice way! Thank you very much for help!
